# NOWAIT with UPDATE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, cursor

How to use `NOWAIT` with `UPDATE` statement in `SQL` Server?

I have read somewhere that `NOWAIT` with `UPDATE` statement in `SQL` Server can be achieved through cursors.

I am not good at writing cursors. Can somebody help me to achieve the same?

I don't know cursors are the only solution for it. If someone knows some other way please do suggest.

Comment: What is your idea of `NOWAIT` behavior?

Comment: There is no `NOWAIT` syntax for `UPDATE`. Explain what you are actually trying to do that requires this.

Comment: I don't think you understand what NOWAIT means. And I certainly don't understand how using a cursor would help here.